# Linker on VC 2008 Express:

Tags: visual-c++

So I'm attempting to build something:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: some_project, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>Linking...
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'CGAL-vc90-mt.lib'
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\Whoever\Documents\some_project\some_project.dir\Release\BuildLog.htm"
1>some_project - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have a `CGAL-vc90-mt.lib` but I don't know where in the directory tree to drop it in so the build process above can find it.  I don't even know where to look to find out where it expects to find it presently.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project settings, then "Configuration Properties" then "Linker" then "General" and add the directory where your lib file is in the "additionnal library directories".
This is from visual c++ 2010, but I am quite confident it similar in vc 2008.

Comment: Thank you for answering. So I go there and added the path to the CGAL-vc90-mt.lib, but the build still didn't pick it up. Where is the build even getting the name of that library from?